# How to simplify this integral? Algebraic manipulation doesn't seem to help

Tags: integration

I am a bit stuck on this integral problem:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x + x \sqrt{x}}$$

I tried multiplying top and bottom by $x - x \sqrt{x},$ but that just leaves me with

$$\int \frac{x - x\sqrt{x}}{x^2 + x^3},$$

and that doesn't seem any better of a situation. Multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{x}$ still leaves me with an odd square root on the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried the rationalizing substitution $u^2 = x$?

Comment: Oh so I can say $u = \sqrt{x}$ and $u^2 = x$ right which replaces all of the nastiness in the denominator right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use substitution:
$\; \sqrt x=t\iff x=t^2,\;t>0$, $\;\mathrm dx=2t\,\mathrm d t$, to obtain the integral of a rational function, then proceed to a decomposition into partial fractions.

Comment: Oh so I can say $u = \sqrt{x}$ and $u^2 = x$ right which replaces all of the nastiness in the denominator right?

Comment: Absolutely. After that, you have to go back to the original variable (which is simple in the present case).

Comment: I wind up with $\int \frac{2udu}{u^2 + u^3}$ which seems better but not quite there yet...

Comment: Simplify first, and use partial fractions: this  fraction rewrites as $\frac Au+ \frac B{1+u}$ for constants $A$ and $ B$.